# not able to display data in google charts using json

Tags: javascript

I am getting the data from MySQL and want to display it in a line chart using google charts. I am using java and javascript.

**this is the type of data which i am getting from MySQL:**

**timestamp**   2017-06-12 19:22:23.0  , 2017-06-12 19:22:25.0
  **f1**                      414                    413

I got this data in a resultset and converted it into JSONarray and the output is like:
'[{"f1":414,"ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:23.0"},{"f1":415,"ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:25.0"}]'

-> from a servlet i am passing this string to a jsp file.

**Now the JSP file:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello');
});


var newstring =  <%= request.getAttribute("json_string")%>
<%System.out.println(request.getAttribute("json_string"));%>
var chartData = JSON.parse(newstring);


// Load google charts
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages:["corechart, table"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



// Draw the chart and set the chart values



    var dTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dTable.addColumn('string','timestamp'); 
    dTable.addColumn('number','f1');

    for(i=0;i<chartData.length;i++)
    {
        var currentObj = chartData[i];
        dTable.addRow([currentObj.f1,currentObj.ts]);
    }


  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="linechart"
    var options = {'title':'<%= request.getAttribute("Spring_type") + " for date :"%><%= request.getAttribute("date")%>', 'width':550, 'height':400};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);



</script>
```

**The chart is not getting displayed.**

**Any help would be appreciated. Or if there is any other way please write it down.**

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No.. No error..

Comment: Then make sure the parent element that you are rendering your chart in has a height

Comment: also inspect elements to see if the chart elements are present in the dom

Comment: sorry .. I am not that really good in javascript.. If you can provide more details or any link. Below is the div in which I am displaying chart 
<div id="linechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> rest of the code I have posted above

Comment: right click in your browser and select inspect then go to the elements tab and try to find the div with id linechart there , and see if there is anything present inside it.

Comment: thanks for the help... Nothing is present inside the div..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all your values to dTable while your are using some variable data while creating the chart, the correct way should be

```
chart.draw(dTable , options);
```

and there is no drawChart function , you should wrap everything in the function lioke

```
function drawChart(){
var dTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dTable.addColumn('string','timestamp'); 
    dTable.addColumn('number','f1');

    for(i=0;i<chartData.length;i++)
    {
        var currentObj = chartData[i];
        dTable.addRow([currentObj.f1,currentObj.ts]);
    }


  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="linechart"
    var options = {'title':'<%= request.getAttribute("Spring_type") + " for date :"%><%= request.getAttribute("date")%>', 'width':550, 'height':400};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));
      chart.draw(dTable , options);

}
```

Also look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) example from the api docs

Comment: @NikhilKumawat Updated my answer